# Many apps depending on the server name Yii2

Tags: php, yii

I need to have many yii apllications in this way:

```
www.domain.com / domain.com => Application #1

companyID*.domain.com => Application #2 (e.g. company1.domain.com, company2.domain.com...)

crm.domain.com => Application #3
```

In the entry script (`web/index.php`) there are some logic that creates and configures these applications depending on the server name (I don't know if it's right, may be it's better to do this on the server side).

So, the question is: How to properly create and configure several applications (both for web and console apps)?

Is there a detailed instruction somewhere?

And if you know, what this architecture is called, when different applications are created depending on the name of the subdomain (from example above).

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a different config per domain, or truly different behavior per application, with some shared functionality and shared DB if so take a look at the advance template of Yii https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md

Comment: Yes it will be applications with a separate functionality. In general, the advanced template suits me, but I don't understand how to send requests like: `company1.domain.com, company2.domain.com, company3.domain.com ...` to a separate application, say, which will be called "company".

Comment: So the advanced template is somewhat more complex to use but offers a lot of features. You can configure your domains using yii environments see https://www.my-yii.com/learn/view-episode/how-to-create-and-use-environments-in-yii-2-basic-application-template and make them easily accessible using vhost see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html